# Prisma: Query across multiple schemas in a database

Tags: node.js, graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql, prisma2

Does prisma support the ability to fetch data from multiple schemas from within a single database?

Comment: Hey! What do you mean exactly with this? With "schema", do you mean a "GraphQL schema" or a "[PostgreSQL schema](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/ddl-schemas.html)" or something else?

Comment: the latter one. @nburk

Comment: Did you find a solution for using multiple Postgres schema's with Prisma? This is one thing that is preventing me from using it.

Comment: @Jonathan, we'd to drop Prisma just because of this limitations. I haven't checked Prisma after it, whether they support it now or not.

Comment: What did you end up using?

Comment: GraphQL with simple Sequelize in one product (that required multi-tenancy) and GraphQL and Dynamo DB using AWS SAM at another.

@Jonathan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is not yet possible. Here's a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/1122) that had been created you can use to monitor the feature's status and give your feedback too.

Could you also share your use case too? Your feedback will be highly appreciated as we relay it back to the team.

Answer (score 0):

Prisma `multiSchema` is now supported as a preview feature.

See here https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/database/multi-schema

It was introduced in version 4.3.0 https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/1122#issuecomment-1231773471

As the docs say you would add the preview feature...

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  previewFeatures = ["multiSchema"]
}
```

Then in your datasource you note the schemas...

```
datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
  schemas  = ["schema1", "schema2"]
}
```

And finally in each model you add the `@@schema` attribute...

```
model User {
  id      Int      @id
  orders  Order[]
  profile Profile?

  @@schema("schema1")
}

model Order {
  id      Int  @id
  user    User @relation(fields: [id], references: [id])
  user_id Int

  @@schema("schema2")
}
```